# Get percentage of category in tableau interactive dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to calculate percentage of a particular category based on the selection in the dashboard.

I have a column called diag and it has the below values:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to build a KPI and populate the same in interactive dashboard. If a user selects `a` from the drop down the KPI should show 30% in the dashboard and if he selects `b` then 20%.

I tried to achieve this by using calculated field `count[diag]/count[diag]`  but unable to figure out how to pass that field dynamically to the numerator? Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an LOD to get the total as your denominator. In this case, I'm using the default count of records based on the data source name.

[image]